# Bluemix Docker Container deployment results in "No route to host"

Tags: spring, postgresql, docker, containers, ibm-cloud

we are deploying a docker-image using this command:

```
cf ic run -p 8080 -m 512 -e SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=test -e logging.config=classpath:logback-docker-test.xml --name <container-name> registry.eu-gb.bluemix.net/<repository_name>/<container-name>:latest
```

Within that container we are starting a Java8 Spring-Boot application that uses a connection-pooling provider. The connection-pooling provider connects to an existing PostgreSQL-Database that is accessible on the standard port. We do not use any domain name to connect to PostgreSQL-Database. We only use the IP-Address and the standard postgresql port.

The deployment is working on a machine that uses the standard Docker container daemon and is also working on Amazon WebServices (AWS) without any problems and using the same deployment mechanism.

However, if we are deploying the image to the Bluemix-Container-Service we do get the following error at startup of the spring-boot application:

```
Caused by: java.net.NoRouteToHostException: No route to host
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:61)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:129)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:65)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:146)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:35)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:22)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc42.AbstractJdbc42Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc42Connection.java:21)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc42.Jdbc42Connection.<init>(Jdbc42Connection.java:28)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:415)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.access$100(Driver.java:47)
    at org.postgresql.Driver$ConnectThread.run(Driver.java:325)
    ... 1 more
```

We don't know why this happens, because if we do a telnet on another Bluemix-Docker-Machine to the PostgreSQL-Database server with the desired port everything is fine.

This is very annoying, since we cannot use this Docker-Image on Bluemix currently and is currently obstructing our planned roll-out.

Can you help us with details what might be wrong and how can fix this?

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Official bluemix support gave the hint to wait for 120 seconds before starting the Java-Application that needs network access. The suggested way is:

```
CMD ["/bin/sh", "-c", "sleep 120; exec java $JVM_ARGS -cp /app org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher --spring.main.show_banner=false"]
```

With that we have got network access and everything is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is this error raised when the container is starting up?
If so, the Docker/IBM Containers on Bluemix take about between 30 up to 60 seconds in networking status: during this phase the container is not able to connect to the network.
It should be really probably the root cause of the error you are getting: if the Java SpringBoot application is trying to connect to the PostgreSQL database when the container is still in networking phase, it will fail with this error.
You should start your application running on the container when the container has completed the networking phase (for example through a bash script that checks the availability of the PostgreSQL server, or simply configure your springboot to manage this exception)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and comment.

Unfortunately, this is a little disappointing because on the Docker Service at AWS or using Docker directly on one of your internal systems erverything is fine with the same Docker-Image. So we only have to do some modifications at the Docker-Image to support Bluemix. I think this is not the idea behind an independent docker-image.

Anyway, do you have got a suggestion/hint to wait until the network connection has been established?